# How to disable security in chrome for temporary purpose

Tags: google-chrome

I need to disable this error regarding  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present.I need to make sure that this error is gone and just test an api call.

Answer (score 0):

chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security